# Структура таблицы MySQL для архивирования данных различных типов

Tags: mysql

Необходимо в таблицу с определенной периодичностью заносить значения различных параметров. Значения могут быть целочисленные, дробные и булевые (хотелось бы еще строки, но не обязательно).

Сейчас структура такая:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tag_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`date` - время измерения;
`value` - значение параметра;
`tag_id` - ссылка на другую таблицу с описанием параметра.

Чутье подсказывает, что хранить числа в строке неправильно. Как быть, посоветуете?

Comment: В принципе как-то неправильно, получается, задание поставлено.
Ибо разнотипные данные хранить в одном месте не айс.

А как решение - да, ваш вариант подходит.  
Поле типа varchar, а дальше вам придется извлекать из строки данные в нужном типе.  
Или можно еще вариант, в таблице создать поля value_int, value_dec, value_bool, value_str - и заполнять только нужное поле, а остальные по дефолту НУЛЛами писать.

Comment: Вариант с несколькими полями я тоже рассматривал, не нравится, что более навороченный select получается.
Еще интересует вопрос производительности. Запись в эту таблицу идет постоянно, раз в несколько секунд, чтение гораздо реже (когда захочется график построить) с выборкой по tag_id. Счет перевалил за миллион.

Comment: @dzukp, что такое MUL?)

Comment: Про MUL ничего не скажу. Таблицу сгенерировала Django по нижеприведенной модели.
tag_id - foreigh key на другую таблица, видимо это и означает MUL.

    class ArchiveTag(models.Model):
        tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag,null=True)
        value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        date = models.DateTimeField()

Comment: так ведь "целочисленные, дробные и булевые" однозначно хранятся в "дробных"

Comment: если предполагается хранить инфу почти произвольного формата без поиска по ней, то я бы сворачивал в json или сериализовал. И хранил в этом виде. Тогда если форматов добавится, менять ничего не надо

Comment: В целом согласен с предыдущим оратором про json, но хотелось бы понять контекст использования данных. Будет выбираться все скопом и потом парситься на тип или мы будем заранее знать, какого типа значение будет читаться?

Answer (score 3):

По-хорошему надо приводить любой архивируемый тип к типу архива самостоятельно. Например есть сериализация, т.е. перевод любого значения в строку. Или можно конвертировать любой тип в бинарные данные. Соотв. использовать или text/varchar (у последнего ограничение по символам) или blob

Comment: Сериализация не годится, мы привязываем данные к конкретному языку программирования. Если потом приложение переписывается с использованием другого языка - у нас проблема. Плюс мы ограничиваем себя в поиске по такому столбцу. В крайнем случае можно использовать JSON, но в MySQL столбец такого типа появился только начиная с MySQL 5.7. Хотелось бы чисто реляционное решение.

Comment: Как вариант, конвертацию типов можно реализовать через хранимые процедуры MySQL.

Comment: @cheops сериализация как раз не привязывается к языку программирования

Comment: @Etki, можете расшифровать? В PHP свой формат сериализации, в Ruby - своя маршилизация. Сохраненные в таком формате данные потом довольно трудно извлечь при переезде проекта на другую платформу, когда использование конкретного языка не очень удобно. Возможно имеется в виду что-то другое, с чем я не знаком или что-то что я не учитываю?

Comment: @cheops то, что встроенная функция называется serialize, не говорит что сериализация - это какой-то атрибут конкретного языка, и уж тем более не значит, что сериализовать нужно ей. Сериализация - это просто процесс превращения внутренних структур данных языка в строку / байтовый массив / etc. Поэтому запись в виде json / xml / protobuf вполне подпадает под понятие сериализации; более того, нативную сериализацию php можно десериализовать на любом языке (но не нужно), поэтому формально это тоже не является преградой.

Comment: @Etki, согласен, но на практике не удобно, так как фактически это антипатерн, типа хранения идентификаторов через запятую. СУБД это допускает, однако редактирование таких данных превращается в ад - нужно удалять и перезаписывать по-новой. При таком подходе мы теряем преимущества СУБД и сталкиваемся с ее недостатками.

Comment: @cheops это не антипаттерн, это единственное нормальное решение, тесно трущееся о сопротивление статической типизации БД. *нужно удалять и перезаписывать по-новой* - если грубо, то так почти всегда происходит в БД (кроме, может быть, реляционок), это нормальная ситуация. Про поиск - мы не ограничиваем, он остается таким же (неудобным), большой разницы, ищем мы `value_bool = 1` или `value = '"true"'`, нет, зато сериализация дает возможность записывать абсолютно любые значения (в т.ч. со вложенностью).

Comment: Хорошее решение кстати. Значение хранить в varchar, и добавить еще одно поле varchar с описанием, какого типа значение сохранено.

Answer (score 1):

Можете хранить значения в отдельных колонках: столько колонок, сколько у вас "параметров". Каждая колонка с нужным типом, у каких-то колонок тип может совпадать, это непринципиально. Все колонки с атрибутом `NULL`. Это как раз тот случай, когда null-able уместен.

```
CREATE TABLE `multi` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field_a` int(10) NULL,
  `field_b` float(10,2) NULL,
  `field_c` tinyint(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Писать и добывать в/из разных колонки зависимости от `tag_id`. 
Если понадобится имитировать одну универсальную колонку, то можно использовать доступ к полю по номеру:

```
SELECT tag_id, ELT(tag_id, field_a, field_b, field_c) AS value
FROM multi
```

Comment: Таблица будет несуразно здоровенная и дырявая(индексы тоже). Помимо дискового пространства, чревато просадкой производительности

Comment: Ну и пусть дырявая. Объем дискового пространства сейчас имеет самый низкий приоритет. Главное — удобство использования. Про производительность аргументируйте пожалуйста. Сравните с "универсальным текстовым" вариантом и с "сериализованным blob".

Comment: @rjhdby почитайте про объемы и производительность null: http://stackoverflow.com/a/230923/272885

Comment: чем толще таблица, тем меньшее количество ее страниц поместится в память.

Comment: Почитайте по ссылке, попробуйте. Осторожно, шаблоны могут порваться. По крайней мере для InnoDB место расходуется чуть. А выгода от типизованных полей очевидна.

Comment: Уважаемый, вы сами то по ссылке читали? Рекомендую. И комменты. Осторожно, шаблоны могут порваться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39609/discussion-between-artoodetoo-and-rjhdby).

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, задача не полна без описания алгоритма дальнейшего использования. По какому принципу потом в эту таблицу будут запросы делаться?

Почему tag_id может быть NULL? Насколько я понимаю, именно по нему будет определяться, что же за параметр тут сохранен?

Так-то делал бы так. Допускаем, что в таблице с описанием есть поле type, описывающие тип параметра

```
CREATE TABLE main (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
tag_id int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE int_values (
id int(11),
value int(11),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES main(id)
);

CREATE TABLE bool_values (
id int(11),
value BOOL,
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES main(id)
);
```

и так далее.

Comment: В тексте вы упоминаете поле type, но в структуре его не видно.

Comment: это отсылка к постановке задачи. tag_id - ссылка на другую таблицу с описанием параметра.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не завести по таблице на каждый тип + таблицу-индекс?